# liferay 6.2 addDLFolder fail

Tags: web-services, liferay

I tried to build a webservice for external system to upload documents.
Each user create a unique folder to store the documents himself uploaded.
In order to that,I was thinking to create different folder with unique name.
I looked up API and find a `DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.addFolder`(parameter list is way too long to type) method.

The param `serviceContext` is required and I can't seem to find a way to retrieve it.
So, I put NULL instead. After I build and deploy, I call the method which contains `addFolder()` from client, `NullPointerException` occurs on server and an axis exception occurs on client.

faultCode:

```
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException, faultString: java.rmi.RemoteException.
```

Is it because I put NULL as a parameter instead of an instance of `serviceContext`?

If so,how can I get the instance of `serviceContext`? If I can not, where else could be the problem?

Here's my paramlist:

```
DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.addFolder(user.getUserId(), user.getGroupId(), user.getGroupId(), true, 10157, "test", "description", false, null);
```

Comment: This issue seems of permission, it checks for permission before adding folder/file, you can call this method with proper credentials

Comment: It's not that, I've fixed this bug, along with some more.But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could also give [DLAppLocalServiceUtil.addFolder](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLAppLocalServiceUtil.html#addFolder(long,%20long,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext)) a try.

Similarly, the Service Context is a parameter, but I'm able to create a folder with the following

```
final Folder folder = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.addFolder(
                    getThemeDisplay().getUserId(),
                    getThemeDisplay().getScopeGroupId(),
                    DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID,
                    "Folder Name",
                    "Folder Description",
                    new ServiceContext());
```

In my particular use case, I use the `ThemeDisplay` from the request object to organize my Document Media elements:

```
(ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY)
```

**Note:** Also in my particular usage, the user that triggers the folder creation will have elevated permissions, as such permissioning may be an issue for non-admin users.